# Powershell - Enumeration through multi tiered JSON output using INVOKE-RESTMETHOD

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to return a certain value from some multi-tiered JSON output from a rest API, and can't seem to use the returned output correctly, especially when you don't know what could be in that output (most examples I have seen about this ASSUME you already know the fields returned and can hardcode these in, but not in this case).

The API in question is an F5 Local Traffic Manager Rest API...

The returned JSON looks like this. I'm looking to get the value of **serverside.curConns** out of this...

```
{
      "generation": 263285,
      "kind": "tm:ltm:pool:members:membersstats",
      "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Production~Frontend_App_pool/members/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/stats?ver=12.1.3",
      "entries": {
        "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Production~Frontend_App_pool/members/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/stats": {
          "nestedStats": {
            "kind": "tm:ltm:pool:members:membersstats",
            "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Production~Frontend_App_pool/members/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/stats?ver=12.1.3",
            "entries": {
              "serverside.curConns": {
                "value": 0
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
```

My issue is that the first "entries" container above will change on every server I run this against, and this is what I am trying to code around, but with no success so far.

My Powershell script currently looks like this...

```
$f5partition = "Production"
# ======= CHANGE PER ENVIRONMENT ==========
$f5poolname = "Frontend_App_pool"
$f5port = 8080
$user = "myf5userid"
$pass = "myf5password"
$f5server = "myf5server.mydomain.local"
# ======= NO CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE! =======
$servername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
# ====== AUTHORISATION SECTION ==========
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}
#=== CONNECT TO F5 API =========
$reply = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://${f5server}/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~${f5partition}~${f5poolname}/members/~${f5partition}~${servername}:${f5port}/stats/?$select=serverside.curConns -Headers $Headers
```

When I run this the first time, it is possible (using Powershell's ISE) to tab-through the results of $reply, so I end up with a value of 0 as expected...

```
Write-Host $reply.entries.'https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Production~Frontend-App_pool/members/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/stats'.nestedStats.entries.'serverside.curConns'.value
```

This is great. For the server PROD_SERVER01 though. I can't then save that script and run it against PROD_SERVER02 for example because its now hard-coded in the script.

What I really need is something like $reply.entries.*.nestedStats.entries.'serverside.curConns'.value, or some way I can interrogate and work around returned JSON values that are not predetermined in any way.

Any help greatly received on this, thank you

I'm attempting to code a script that has no baggage or tools that need to be copied to other servers to run, such as modules or other .exe's. and this Invoke-RestMethod is almost doing what I want, but I am struggling with enumerating through the output when it is using a field that isn't expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can convert the JSON to XML and use XPath to get what you need. Tested and working:

```
# question's original JSON sample above
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $s;

# change -depth to suit your needs
$xml = ConvertTo-Xml -NoTypeInformation $json -Depth 10;
# if you want to take a look at JSON => XML.
# pretty-print only works in PowerShell console, not ISE
$xml.Save([Console]::Out);

# 0, what you're looking for....
$wanted = $xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(
              '//Property[@Name="serverside.curConns"]'
          ).FirstChild.InnerText;
```

IMHO parsing JSON with PowerShell is painful/severely lacking - there should be built-in support to parse nested JSON objects.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I agree with you on the Powershell/JSON front, it is clearly lacking. I did think this was impossible, and converting it to XML to navigate through goes some way to prove it. Amazing when you think Microsoft Azure uses JSON and Powershell to do service provisioning!

Answer (score -1):

The magic is in using $yourObject.psobject

```
$json = @"
{
      "generation": 263285,
      "kind": "tm:ltm:pool:members:membersstats",
      "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Production~Frontend_App_pool/members/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/stats?ver=12.1.3",
      "entries": {
        "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Production~Frontend_App_pool/members/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/stats": {
          "nestedStats": {
            "kind": "tm:ltm:pool:members:membersstats",
            "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Production~Frontend_App_pool/members/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/~Production~PROD_SERVER01:8080/stats?ver=12.1.3",
            "entries": {
              "serverside.curConns": {
                "value": 0
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$entryName = $json.entries.psobject.Properties.Name

$json.entries.$($entryName).nestedStats.entries.'serverside.curConns'.value
```